# Use a list to assign a id to a dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, pattern-matching

Lets say i have a list containing names and Ids. Like this:

```
l <- structure(list(Kopen = 11, Nodig = 12, `Maat niet Goed? Gratis Retour` = 21, 
    `Ontdek de Nieuwe Collectie.` = 22, `Bestel NU, Morgen in Huis` = 23, 
    `Al Meer Dan 1 Miljoen Tevreden Klanten. Ontdek De Mooiste Collectie Van Ons Land` = 31, 
    `Meer Dan %N% %ad_group%, Altijd Op Voorraad! Scherpe Prijzen.Bestel Nu.` = 32, 
    `Bestel nu! Alle maten %ad_group% van %merk%, direct uit voorraad leverbaar` = 33), .Names = c("Kopen", 
"Nodig", "Maat niet Goed? Gratis Retour", "Ontdek de Nieuwe Collectie.", 
"Bestel NU, Morgen in Huis", "Al Meer Dan 1 Miljoen Tevreden Klanten. Ontdek De Mooiste Collectie Van Ons Land", 
"Meer Dan %N% %ad_group%, Altijd Op Voorraad! Scherpe Prijzen.Bestel Nu.", 
"Bestel nu! Alle maten %ad_group% van %merk%, direct uit voorraad leverbaar"
))

$Kopen
[1] 11

$Nodig
[1] 12

$`Maat niet Goed? Gratis Retour`
[1] 21

$`Ontdek de Nieuwe Collectie.`
[1] 22

$`Bestel NU, Morgen in Huis`
[1] 23

$`Al Meer Dan 1 Miljoen Tevreden Klanten. Ontdek De Mooiste Collectie Van Ons Land`
[1] 31

$`Meer Dan %N% %ad_group%, Altijd Op Voorraad! Scherpe Prijzen.Bestel Nu.`
[1] 32

$`Bestel nu! Alle maten %ad_group% van %merk%, direct uit voorraad leverbaar`
[1] 33
```

Now i want to use this list to identify elements in my dataframe which looks like this:

```
df <- structure(list(Headline1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("brand1-Trainingspak Kopen", "brand1-Trainingspak Nodig?"
), class = "factor"), Headline2 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Maat niet Goed? Gratis Retour", 
"Ontdek de Nieuwe Collectie."), class = "factor"), Description = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Al Meer Dan 1 Miljoen Tevreden Klanten. Ontdek De Mooiste Collectie Van Ons Land", 
"Bestel nu! Alle Trainingspakken van brand1 ®, direct uit voorraad leverbaar."
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Headline1", "Headline2", "Description"
), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

The ids are the values in the list, e.g. 11,12,21,22,23,31,32,33.

The result i expect is:

```
Headline1   Headline1_id  Headline2                    Headline2_id
Kopen       11            Ontdek de Nieuwe Collectie.  22
Nodig       12            Ontdek de Nieuwe Collectie.  22
```

I tried to use `pmatch, %in%, match, grep and grepl` in combinations with `sapply, lapply and vapply`. But unfortunately i couldn't get the patterns to match properly. Is there any quick solution available for this?

So to wrap up once more:

names(l) should be matched against `Headline1`, `Headline2` and `Description` separately. Then create a new column and add the id if an element is identified.

Comment: you will also have NAs right? i.e. `Headerline2[3]`

Comment: Yes, if there is no match it should be NA. If i am correct now the entire data frame should match to the IDS, but indeed on different rows. Therefor one introduces NAs.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if you are asking for this (or maybe it gives you some ideas):

`cbind(df, apply(df, 1:2, getElement, object = l))[c(1,4,2,5,3,6)]`

Comment: Indeed, this works for al the perfect matches. But can i also do this with a partial match. Would make my life way more easy. Thanks! To eleborate:
Bestel nu! Alle maten %ad_group% van %merk%, direct uit voorraad leverbaar Should match Bestel nu! Alle Trainingspakken van brand1 ®, direct uit voorraad leverbaar.

Comment: can you give other examples of the matching? i mean, it is not easy to do this match bc another string also starts with bestel nu; or do you mean, perhaps that the sentences are the same but the words inbetween %?

Comment: sorry for the late response. I was on a holiday. The IDS, should be assigned based on differences in the sentences. So indeed the percentage sign could be used to select those ids. Ideally i dont need any matching. But i generate IDS, based on the sentence. But converting to numeric will not work because then it will change every time i use the keywords again. In another context and that is something i do not want. The % i use for pattern replacements, and fill with particular keywords specific for a subject.